# What does "~mitochondrial DNA ~bp linear DNA" means?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna

I'm surfing NCBI website -[Nucleotide](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=sus%20scrofa)- to find some examples of real DNA sequences to use in my small homework project.

My question is related to the title of a DNA sequence below:

> Sus scrofa mitochondrial DNA, D-loop region, isolate: Europeanwild boar 3
>
> 1,045 bp linear DNA

I thought a mitochondrial DNA is different than a linear/nuclear DNA, especially that a mitochondrial DNA is circular while a linear/nuclear DNA is linear. So what does the above title actually means (in simple terms)? Is it still linear or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Mitochondrial DNA CAN be linear (in some organism), see the wikipedia page on this

> In most multicellular organisms, the mtDNA - or mitogenome - is
>   organized as a circular, covalently closed, double-stranded DNA. But
>   in many unicellular (e.g. the ciliate Tetrahymena or the green alga
>   Chlamydomonas reinhardtii) and in rare cases also in multicellular
>   organisms (e.g. in some species of Cnidaria) the mtDNA is found as
>   linearly organized DNA. Most of these linear mtDNAs possess telomerase
>   independent telomeres (i.e. the ends of the linear DNA) with different
>   modes of replication, which have made them interesting objects of
>   research, as many of these unicellular organisms with linear mtDNA are
>   known pathogens.[19]
>
> For human mitochondrial DNA (and probably for that of metazoans in
>   general), 100-10,000 separate copies of mtDNA are usually present per
>   cell (egg and sperm cells are exceptions). In mammals, each
>   double-stranded circular mtDNA molecule consists of 15,000-17,000[20]
>   base pairs. The two strands of mtDNA are differentiated by their
>   nucleotide content, with a guanine-rich strand referred to as the
>   heavy strand (or H-strand) and a cytosine-rich strand referred to as
>   the light strand (or L-strand). The heavy strand encodes 28 genes, and
>   the light strand encodes 9 genes for a total of 37 genes. Of the 37
>   genes, 13 are for proteins (polypeptides), 22 are for transfer RNA
>   (tRNA) and two are for the small and large subunits of ribosomal RNA
>   (rRNA). This pattern is also seen among most metazoans, although in
>   some cases one or more of the 37 genes is absent and the mtDNA size
>   range is greater. Even greater variation in mtDNA gene content and
>   size exists among fungi and plants, although there appears to be a
>   core subset of genes that are present in all eukaryotes (except for
>   the few that have no mitochondria at all). Some plant species have
>   enormous mtDNAs (as many as 2,500,000 base pairs per mtDNA molecule)
>   but, surprisingly, even those huge mtDNAs contain the same number and
>   kinds of genes as related plants with much smaller mtDNAs.[21]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA

In the case of your sequence, it only means that it has been entered in NCBI as a linear piece of DNA (it is usually the case when you sequence only a piece of a circular DNA for example)
It does not mean that within the organism it is linear !

I hope this answers your question !